# How to untar an archive that has only a single directory inside and rename it to a constant name

Tags: bash, archive, tar

Most tar software releases do contain a directory with the version included, like `product-1.2.3` and I am looking for a simple bash solution to untar such an archive to a directory that does not contain the version.

Note, the tar archive name is different than the directory contained inside.

Obviously, one approach is to rename it after but in order to do this you need to know what was the original directory name.

Comment: `Note, the tar archive name is different than the directory contained inside.` can you make an example to show what result do you want to have?

Comment: There are many possible conditions. How do you decide when to include/exclude the default root directory of the files inside the archive? Would you base the new directory from the archive's name or from the directory inside?

Answer (score 0):

Two options useful here:

```
File name transformations:
       --strip-components=NUMBER
              strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
Common options:
       -C, --directory=DIR
              change to directory DIR
```

E.g.

```
[user@host tmp]$ mkdir test-0.0.2
[user@host tmp]$ echo Hello > test-0.0.2/README
[user@host tmp]$ tar zvcf mytarball.tgz test-0.0.2
test-0.0.2/
test-0.0.2/README
[user@host tmp]$ mkdir targetdir
[user@host tmp]$ tar zxvf mytarball.tgz --strip-components=1 -C targetdir
test-0.0.2/README
[user@host tmp]$ ls targetdir/
README
[user@host tmp]$
```